# logout and registration not working on laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, registration, logout

i am having complications with logging out, when I try to log out i get this error message:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 721:
Class App\Http\Controllers\LoginController does not exist
```

and when trying to register i get this error:

```
ErrorException in RegisterController.php line 59:
Undefined index: f_name
```

can someone please help me point out where im going wrong?
cheers

web.php

```
Route::get('allbooks', 'BookController@allbooks');
Route::get('sellform', 'BookController@sell');
Route::post('sellbook', 'BookController@sellbook');
Route::get('allusers', 'BookController@allUsers');
Route::get('details/{bookId}', 'BookController@details');
Route::get('addform', 'BookController@addForm');
Route::post('addbook', 'BookController@addBook');
Route::get('deleteform', 'BookController@deleteForm');
Route::post('deletebooks', 'BookController@deleteBook');
Route::get('requests', 'BookController@requests');
Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@create');
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/profile', 'HomeController@profile');
Route::get('/oneweek/{bookId}', 'HomeController@oneweek');
Route::get('/twoweek/{bookId}', 'HomeController@twoweek');
Route::get('/fourweek/{bookId}', 'HomeController@fourweek');
Route::post('loan', 'HomeController@loan');
Route::get('allloans', 'HomeController@allloans');
```

LoginController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
| redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
| to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
|
*/

use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}

}
```

RegisterController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
| validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
|
*/
use RegistersUsers;
/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}
/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'f_name' => 'string|max:255',
        'l_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'f_name' => $data['f_name'],
        'l_name' => $data['l_name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'role' => '1'
    ]);
    }
}
```

User.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Login Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
| redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
| to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
|
*/

use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}

}
```

this is the part of my layout blade that has the logout button

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @if (Auth::guest())
                        <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"onclick="event.preventDefault(); 
                        document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">Logout</a>

                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                        </form>

                    @endif
```

Comment: The first issue sounds like `Auth::routes()` is behaving in a non-standard fashion. It should be adding the routes with the `App\Http\Controllers\Auth` namespace already. You'll want to check the `Illuminate\Routing\Router::auth` method to be sure it's unmodified (see: [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L994))

Comment: For the second issue, try adding a `dd($data)` at the top of the `create` method in the `RegistrationController` to see what's in the `$data` var. If I had to guess your registration form has these properties named differently or is just missing them all together.

Answer (score 0):

Your second issue is related to you redefining the `register` `post` route to the wrong controller method.

Delete this from your routes

```
Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@create');
```

`Auth::routes` already defines the register routes

```
$this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
$this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
```

As for the logout issue. The default logout action redirects the users to the base url `/`. The logout route and controller comes with laravel, so there should be no issues unless you've changed them. Try running `composer dump-autoload` and check if you're continuing to receive the errors.